# foreach loop error in wcf workflow service application

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, for-loop, workflow

I have a workflow with 3 services and I want to check the condition for each input automatically,so I used a foreach loop to do this,but I faced by error.What should I do now?
here the error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'UniversityList.StudentInfo' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

[the picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGqSg.jpg)

```
new UniversityList.StudentInfo() {NationalKey=san.NationalKey}
```

Comment: could you please include snippet

Comment: You should post the code on here to get help.

Comment: Can we get more of the code?  Like the whole block?  At this point, we don't even know what you are setting this equal to and that is where your issue is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a foreach loop, you need a collection of items and not just a single item.  You can make a single item a collection by doing this.

```
new List<UniversityList.StudentInfo>(new UniversityList.StudentInfo[] 
    {
        new UniversityList.StudentInfo
        { 
            NationalKey=san.NationalKey
        }
    })
```

The list implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable and will get ride of your error.

Comment: I don`t have any block code.It is a workflow and I have to write the code in the box.you can see the picture of workflow above,in the question.

Comment: The answer above is a single line of code that initializes a List of your objects.  I just put it on multiple lines to make sure parentheses matched.